# NullpointerException error while editing any component inside panel

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, fxml

I'm trying to change the text of a label inside a panel, but whenever I try to make any changes in the components of that panel I get the error NullPointer.
My program works with a worksheet to store the data and show to the user

FXMLDocumetController.java (I used the 'alterarTela(int tela)' method to switch between panels):

```
package agenda;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane paneFundo;
    @FXML
    private JFXListView<Label> listView;
    @FXML
    private JFXTextField txtPesquisar;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnPesquisar;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton FAB;

    ArrayList <String> urlTelas = new ArrayList<String>();
    Arquivo arquivo = new Arquivo();
    PaneInfoPessoa paneInfoPessoa = new PaneInfoPessoa();
    PaneInfoPA paneInfoPa = new PaneInfoPA();

    @FXML
    public void btnPesquisarClique (ActionEvent e) {

    }

    @FXML
    public void FABClique (ActionEvent e) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Tela add abrir");
        alterarTela(2);
    }

    @FXML
    public void itemListaSelecionado()  {
        String nome[] = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getText().split("\n");
        if (nome[0].startsWith("PA")) {
            alterarTela(1);
            System.out.println("Tela alterada 1");
            paneInfoPa.atualizarDados(arquivo.pegarPaLista(nome[0]));
        } else {
            alterarTela(0);
            System.out.println("Tela alterada 0");
            paneInfoPessoa.atualizarDados(arquivo.pegarPessoaLista(nome[0]));
        }
    }



    public void alterarTela(int tela) {
        try {
            Pane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(urlTelas.get(tela)));
            paneFundo.getChildren().setAll(pane);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("Erro na função alterar tela " + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        urlTelas.add("PaneInfoPessoa.fxml");
        urlTelas.add("PaneInfoPA.fxml");
        urlTelas.add("PaneAdd.fxml");
        listView.setItems(arquivo.lerPlanilha(0, true));
        listView.setFixedCellSize(60);
        listView.setFocusTraversable(false);
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (Observable, oldValue, newValue) -> itemListaSelecionado());
    }      
}
```

Arquivo.java (to set and get data from worksheet):

```
package agenda;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import jxl.Sheet;


public class Arquivo {

    private List<Label> listaContatos = new ArrayList<>();
    private ObservableList<Label> obsListaContatos;


    public ObservableList<Label> lerPlanilha(int num_planilha, boolean lerTodas) {
        if (lerTodas) {
            try {
                int contPlanilhas = Agenda.workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
                for (int j = 0; j < contPlanilhas; j++ ) {
                    List<Label> listaContatos2 = new ArrayList<>();
                    Sheet planilha = Agenda.workbook.getSheet(j);
                    int linhas = planilha.getRows();
                    for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
                        String colunaNome = planilha.getCell(0, i).getContents();
                        String colunaFixo = planilha.getCell(2, i).getContents();
                        listaContatos2.add(new Label(colunaNome + "\n" + colunaFixo));
                    }
                    //TODO ordenar
                    listaContatos.addAll(listaContatos2);
                }
                obsListaContatos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listaContatos);
                return obsListaContatos;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro na função lerPlanilha" + e.toString());
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Sheet planilha = Agenda.workbook.getSheet(num_planilha);
                int linhas = planilha.getRows();
                for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
                    String colunaNome = planilha.getCell(0, i).getContents();
                    String colunaFixo = planilha.getCell(2, i).getContents();
                    listaContatos.add(new Label(colunaNome + "\n" + colunaFixo));
                }
                obsListaContatos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listaContatos);
                return obsListaContatos;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Erro na função lerPlanilha" + e.toString());
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public Pessoa pegarPessoaLista(String nome) {
        int linhaSel = -1;
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
        Sheet planilha = Agenda.workbook.getSheet(1);
        int linhas = planilha.getRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
            if (planilha.getCell(0, i).getContents().equals(nome)) {
                linhaSel = i;
            }
        }
        if (linhaSel >= 0) {
            pessoa.setNome(planilha.getCell(0, linhaSel).getContents());
            pessoa.setRamal(planilha.getCell(1, linhaSel).getContents());
            pessoa.setCelular(planilha.getCell(2, linhaSel).getContents());
            pessoa.setTelefone(planilha.getCell(3, linhaSel).getContents());
            pessoa.setPa(planilha.getCell(4, linhaSel).getContents());
            pessoa.setSetor(planilha.getCell(5, linhaSel).getContents());
            pessoa.setEmail(planilha.getCell(6, linhaSel).getContents());

            return pessoa;
        } else {
            pessoa.setNome("Erro");
            pessoa.setPa("");
            pessoa.setCelular("");
            pessoa.setTelefone("");
            pessoa.setRamal("");
            pessoa.setSetor("");
            pessoa.setEmail("");

            System.out.println("Pessoa não encontrada na funcao arquivo.pegarPessoaLista");
            return pessoa;
        }   
    }

    public Pessoa pegarPessoaPesquisa() {

        return null;
    }

    public Pa pegarPaLista(String pa) {
        int linhaSel = -1;
        Pa PA = new Pa();
        Sheet planilha = Agenda.workbook.getSheet(0);
        int linhas = planilha.getRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
            if (planilha.getCell(0, i).getContents().equals(pa)) {
                linhaSel = i;
            }
        }
        if (linhaSel >= 0) {
            PA.setNumero(planilha.getCell(0, linhaSel).getContents());
            PA.setRamal(planilha.getCell(1, linhaSel).getContents());
            PA.setFixo1(planilha.getCell(2, linhaSel).getContents());
            PA.setFixo2(planilha.getCell(3, linhaSel).getContents());
            PA.setCelular(planilha.getCell(4, linhaSel).getContents());
            PA.setContPessoas(planilha.getCell(5, linhaSel).getContents());
            PA.setGerente(planilha.getCell(6, linhaSel).getContents());
            PA.setLocal(planilha.getCell(0, linhaSel).getContents());
            System.out.println("Pa selecionado" + PA.getNumero());
            return PA;
        } else {
            PA.setNumero("Erro");
            PA.setRamal("");
            PA.setFixo1("");
            PA.setFixo2("");
            PA.setCelular("");
            PA.setContPessoas("");
            PA.setGerente("");
            PA.setLocal("");

            System.out.println("Pessoa não encontrada na funcao arquivo.pegarPessoaLista");
            return PA;
        }   
    }

    public Pa pegarPaPesquisa() {

        return null;
    }
}
```

PaneInfoPa.java (fx controller of PaneInfoPa.FXML):

```
package agenda;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;


public class PaneInfoPA {

    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnEditar;
    @FXML
    private JFXButton btnRemover;
    @FXML
    private Label txtNumero;
    @FXML
    private Label txtRamal;
    @FXML
    private Label txtTelefone;
    @FXML
    private Label txtTelefone2;
    @FXML
    private Label txtCelular;
    @FXML
    private Label txtContPessoas;
    @FXML
    private Label txtGerente;


    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println("Iniciando tela");
        txtNumero.setText("--");
        txtRamal.setText("--");
        txtTelefone.setText("--");
        txtTelefone2.setText("--");
        txtCelular.setText("--");
        txtContPessoas.setText("--");
        txtGerente.setText("--");
        System.out.println("tela iniciada");
    }

    public void atualizarDados(Pa pa) {
        System.out.println("Alterando Valores do pane info pa - " + pa.getNumero());
        btnEditar.setDisable(true);
        //txtNumero.setText(pa.getNumero());
        /*txtRamal.setText(pa.getRamal());
        txtTelefone.setText(pa.getFixo1());
        txtTelefone2.setText(pa.getFixo2());
        txtCelular.setText(pa.getCelular());
        txtContPessoas.setText(pa.getContPessoas());
        txtGerente.setText(pa.getGerente());*/

        System.out.println("Valores do pane info pa atualizados");

    }

    @FXML
    public void txtGerenteClique(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("btn editar clique");
    }

    @FXML
    public void btnEditarClique(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("btn editar clique");
    }

    @FXML
    public void btnRemoverClique(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("btn remover clique");
    }

}
```

PaneInfoPa.FXML (
I already checked all fx: id of FXML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="418.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="agenda.PaneInfoPA">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="23.0" layoutY="18.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="376.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;">
         <effect>
            <DropShadow color="#00000037" />
         </effect>
         <children>
            <Pane layoutX="18.0" layoutY="240.0" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="188.0" style="-fx-background-color: fafafa; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="5.0" text="Celular" textFill="#16a085">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="txtCelular" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="161.0" text="--">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Pane layoutX="15.0" layoutY="84.0" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="261.0" style="-fx-background-color: fafafa; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="5.0" text="Número / Local" textFill="#16a085">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="txtNumero" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="26.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="241.0" text="--">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children></Pane>
            <Label layoutX="18.0" layoutY="23.0" text="Informações">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Segoe UI" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Separator layoutX="15.0" layoutY="57.0" prefHeight="10.0" prefWidth="339.0" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnEditar" layoutX="213.0" layoutY="22.0" onAction="#btnEditarClique" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="66.0" ripplerFill="#c6c6c6" text="Editar" textFill="#16a085">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Segoe UI Semibold" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnRemover" layoutX="282.0" layoutY="22.0" onAction="#btnRemoverClique" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="74.0" ripplerFill="#cdcdcd" text="Remover" textFill="#e74c3c">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Segoe UI Semibold" size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
            <Pane layoutX="15.0" layoutY="163.0" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="161.0" style="-fx-background-color: fafafa; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="5.0" text="Telefone 1" textFill="#16a085">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="txtTelefone" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="144.0" text="--">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Pane layoutX="191.0" layoutY="163.0" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="167.0" style="-fx-background-color: fafafa; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="5.0" text="Telefone 2" textFill="#16a085">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="txtTelefone2" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="22.0" prefWidth="144.0" text="--">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Pane layoutX="287.0" layoutY="84.0" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="66.0" style="-fx-background-color: fafafa; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="5.0" text="Ramal" textFill="#16a085">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="txtRamal" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="46.0" text="--">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Pane layoutX="225.0" layoutY="240.0" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="131.0" style="-fx-background-color: fafafa; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="5.0" text="Nº de pessoas" textFill="#16a085">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="txtContPessoas" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="103.0" text="--">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Pane layoutX="18.0" layoutY="319.0" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="261.0" style="-fx-background-color: fafafa; -fx-background-radius: 5 5 5 5;">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="5.0" text="Gerente" textFill="#16a085">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="15.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="txtGerente" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" onMouseClicked="#txtGerenteClique" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="241.0" text="--">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Segoe UI" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </Pane>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

FXMLDocument.FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="725.0" style="-fx-background-color: #f1f1f1;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="agenda.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="437.0" fitWidth="418.0" opacity="0.39" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../img/grafismo.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Pane layoutX="418.0" prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="307.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;">
         <children>
            <JFXTextField fx:id="txtPesquisar" focusColor="WHITE" layoutX="64.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="224.0" promptText="Pesquisar" unFocusColor="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXTextField>
            <Separator layoutX="24.0" layoutY="36.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="265.0" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="btnPesquisar" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="16.0" onAction="#btnPesquisarClique" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="34.0" text="Q" />
            <JFXListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="61.0" prefHeight="358.0" prefWidth="278.0" stylesheets="@style.css" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="FAB" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="228.0" layoutY="360.0" onAction="#FABClique" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="54.0" ripplerFill="#a8a8a8" style="-fx-background-radius: 50 50 50 50; -fx-background-color: #16a085;" text="+" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </Pane>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="paneFundo" prefHeight="437.0" prefWidth="418.0" />

   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And the error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at agenda.PaneInfoPA.atualizarDados(PaneInfoPA.java:48)
    at agenda.FXMLDocumentController.itemListaSelecionado(FXMLDocumentController.java:54)
    at agenda.FXMLDocumentController.lambda$0(FXMLDocumentController.java:82)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$34(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:404)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.clearAndSelect(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:356)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListView$ListViewBitSetSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(ListView.java:1403)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:256)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.doSelect(CellBehaviorBase.java:220)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: `@FXML`-annotated fields are only initialized in controllers. You are calling `atualizarDados(...)` on `paneInfoPa`, which is not a controller (it's just an object you create with `PaneInfoPA paneInfoPa = new PaneInfoPA()`).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/ for various ways to get references to controllers and call methods on them.

Comment: I do not understand very well, in each class like paneInfoPa, will I have to create a public void start method?

Comment: No. Why would you think that?

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood, I was seeing some tutorials on scene and stage, and I learned how to switch between screens, but how do I change between the screens inside my AnchorPane located inside the FXMLDocument.fxml? I do not want to simply switch to another screen, I want the background screen (FXMLDocument) to remain, and the other screens appear inside the anchorPane that stays inside the main screen